# Setting sessionState's customProvider programmatically

Tags: asp.net

In my `web.config` file, I've declared 2 sessionState providers:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="SessionProvider1">
    <providers>
        <add name="SessionProvider1" ... />
        <add name="SessionProvider2" ... />
    </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Now I would like to switch the `customProvider` to `SessionProvider2` at run-time... Is there any way to do this, apart from modifying the `web.config` programmatically?

Thanks.

Comment: did u find any solution? Please share if so

Comment: @ZafarYousafi No sorry, there was no direct way to achieve this from code (at that time, not sure now though)